# How get access token for another resource using Microsoft OAuth

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

The user logs in with

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf

Parameters:
client_id=<CLIENT_ID>
response_type=code
scope=XboxLive.signin offline_access
redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URL>
```

And gets an authorization_code M.R3_BAY.5530f5eb...

When using:

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf

grant_type=authorization_code
client_id=<CLIENT_ID>
scope=Xboxlive.signin Xboxlive.offline_access
code=M.R3_BAY.5530f5eb...
redirect_uri=https://localhost/oauth_success
client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>
```

Getting access_token and refresh_token.

I want to use one of these tokens to get another access_token and refresh_token of scopes {https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid offline_access}. I don't want the user to reauthenticate.

Something like that:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=<CLIENT_ID>
scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid offline_access
refresh_token=M.R3_BL2.-CTnwtvT1!SRhk...
grant_type=refresh_token
client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>
```

But it gives me: The request was denied because one or more scopes requested are unauthorized or expired. The user must first sign in and grant the client application access to the requested scope

- I have found how to do this in MSAL using WithExtraScopeToConsent. But I've only found this in MSAL.NET and MSAL.JS. I couldn't find it in MSAL4J. But I'd like to do it with a simple request, without using third-party libraries.

Comment: `The request body must contain the following parameter: 'assertion'` --> so do you set the access token for this value?

Comment: @tiny-wang Yes of course, but it seems that the point is that this query does not allow me to do what I need. I need to use refresh_token of scope https://graph.microsoft.com/.default to get access_token and refresh_token for scope XboxLive.signin without revalidating.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results as below:***

I generated the **auth code using below authorize** endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid offline_access
&state=12345
```

[image]

I generated the **access token using authorization code flow** as below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token 

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid offline_access
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

Now by using **On-Behalf-Of flow**, I generated the access token using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token 

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default 
grant_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion:accesstokengeneratedabove
requested_token_use:on_behalf_of
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[GitHub - A Java Web API that calls another web API with the Microsoft identity platform using the On-Behalf-Of flow](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapi)

Comment: Oops, I think I misunderstood how On-Behalf-Of flow works. I don't need it at all. I need to use only one Web Api. Get two tokens, the first for https://graph.microsoft.com/.default the second for XboxLive.signin. 
Something like this: user goes to the link -> confirms permissions -> get access token and refresh token of scope https://graph.microsoft.com/.default -> using the token in the previous step get access token and refresh token of scope XboxLive.signin

Comment: AFAIK, The scenario you are describing is OBO flow.

Comment: @Rukumi Strange, i try it again and it gives me: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The key was not found.] But if i use same scope all fine. I use id_token for access_token it returns: JWT token is invalid or malformed.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot it looks like the "&" is missing in the code, here is the sample code for getting the access token:

[image]

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#example